# Validate IP4 address

Tags: python, interview-questions, validation, ip-address

### Validate IP Address

I got this problem during an interview. And would like to get some code review. I also wrote several tests with the expected output, and they all passed as expected.

> Validate an IP address (IPv4). An address is valid if and only if it
> is in the form "X.X.X.X", where each X is a number from 0 to 255.
>
> For example, "12.34.5.6", "0.23.25.0", and "255.255.255.255" are valid
> IP addresses, while "12.34.56.oops", "1.2.3.4.5", and
> "123.235.153.425" are invalid IP addresses.

```
Examples:

"""    

ip = '192.168.0.1'
output: true

ip = '0.0.0.0'
output: true

ip = '123.24.59.99'
output: true

ip = '192.168.123.456'
output: false
"""

def validateIP(ip):
  #split them by '.' , and store them in an array
  #check the array if the length is 4 length
  arr = ip.split('.')
  if len(arr) != 4:
    return False
  #0 check for special edge cases when non-digit
  #1. check if they are digit, 
  #2. check if check the integer is between 0 and 255
  
  for part in arr:
    if len(part) > 1:
      if part[0] == '0':
        return False
    if not part.isdigit():
      return False
    digit = int(part)
    if digit < 0 or digit > 255:
      return False
  return True

#case#0

ip0="08.0.0.0" # False
test0= validateIP(ip0)
print(test0)

#case#1
ip1 = "192.168.0.1"
test1 = validateIP(ip1)
print(test1)

#case#2
ip2 = '0.0.0.0'
test2 = validateIP(ip2)
print(test2)

#case#3
ip3 = '123.24.59.99'
test3 = validateIP(ip3)
print(test3)

#case#4
ip4 = '192.168.123.456'
test4 = validateIP(ip4)
print(test4)

#case5
ip5 = "255.255.255.255"
test5 = validateIP(ip5)
print(test5)
```

Answer (score 11):

> ```
> def validateIP(ip):
> ```

I would expect a name starting `is` (a useful hint that it returns a Boolean rather than some more complex validation data structure) and explicitly mentioning IP v4 (since the current name is misleading). E.g. `is_valid_IPv4_address`.

---

> ```
>   #split them by '.' , and store them in an array
>   #check the array if the length is 4 length
>   arr = ip.split('.')
>   if len(arr) != 4:
>     return False
> ```

The comments don't tell me anything which the code doesn't already. In general, good comments explain why, not what.

---

> ```
>   #0 check for special edge cases when non-digit
>   #1. check if they are digit, 
>   #2. check if check the integer is between 0 and 255
>
>   for part in arr:
>     .. various conditions which return False
>   return True
> ```

IMO it would be more Pythonic to use `all`: I would boil the whole function down to

```
    parts = ip.split('.')
    return len(parts) == 4 and all(is_valid_IPv4_address_part(part) for part in parts)
```

---

> ```
>     if len(part) > 1:
>       if part[0] == '0':
>         return False
> ```

This isn't in the spec. It's a reasonable constraint, but you should check with the person who gave you the spec before writing the code, or at least put in a comment saying that you're making an assumption about the true intentions of the specifier.

---

> ```
>     if not part.isdigit():
>       return False
> ```

This is buggy. (Before testing I thought there was an issue which should be bounced back to the specifier. Upon testing, I found that some of my test cases caused `validateIP` to throw an exception).

What is the expected output for these test cases?

```
¹.¹.¹.¹
١.١.١.١
...
①.①.①.①
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Good to know, I always thought `str.isdigit` would only return true for `1234567890`. Need to fix an answer I just wrote on another question...

Answer (score 8):

1. A doc string reads nicer then # blockcomments

   Consider making a doc string of that function, so you can do `help(validate_ip)` and it will print the doc string in the interpreter.
2. Adhere to PEP8

   Functions and variables should be `snake_case` ie `def validate_ip(ip):`
3. You could use the `all` keyword to check if each part is correct; this will return `False` for the first failure.
4. Make actual tests that ensure validity

   Instead of printing tests, make actual tests either with `assert` or the modules `doctest` or `unittest`.
5. There is a module that does this for you

   Python is often described as "batteries included", and here you could use the `ipaddress module`, which will validate an IP when you create the `IPv4Adress` object.

## Reworked code

```
import doctest

def validate_ip(ip):
    """
    Checks if the ip address is valid
    args:
        ip (str): The IP address
    ret:
        A boolean: True for a a valid IP
    
    >>> validate_ip('08.0.0.0')
    False

    >>> validate_ip('192.169.0.1')
    True

    >>> validate_ip('0.0.0.0')
    True

    >>> validate_ip('192.168.123.456')    
    False

    >>> validate_ip('oooh.0.0.1')
    False
    """
    ranges = ip.split('.')
    return len(ranges) == 4 \
        and all(
                r.isdigit() and                 # Check for digits
                int(r) in range(0, 256) and     # Check in range of 0-255
                (r[0] != "0" or len(r) == 1)    # Check for leading zero's
                for r in ranges
            )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doctest.testmod()
```

## ipaddress module

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Address

def is_valid_ip(ip):
    try:
        IPv4Address(ip)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```